# R: transforming one column to another

Tags: r

Please, help me! I've got:

```
x  y
0  0
0  0
1  0
0  0
0  0
1  0
0  0
0  0
-1 0
0  0
```

I need:

```
x  y
0  0
0  0
1  1
0  1
0  1
1  1
0  1
0  1
-1 0
0  0
```

There is 1 in column x fill y with 1 forward until there is -1 in column x from where fill y with 0.

Is it possible to do it without using a loop statement?

It is not "R: column reference to itself".
Using cumsum it is not possible get the answer.

Comment: These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may be useful.

Comment: There should be some logic to convert these values, right?

Comment: It's almost `df$y <- cumsum(df$x)` ...but not quite, and the logic isn't explained.

Comment: using cumsum(df$x) you'll see 0 0  1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if your logic is whenever there is `1` in column `x` fill `y` with `1` forward until there is `-1` in column `x` from where fill `y` with `0` and vice versa:

Since you are trying to `fill forward` vectors with previous values, you may want to use `na.locf`(last observation carried forward) function from `zoo` package and set up threshold values before filling forward, which is the first line doing: set the value to be `1` when `x == 1` and `0` when `x == -1` and otherwise set it to be `NA` for `na.locf` to work properly. The first element will be an exception from your output, it seems that you want the default to be zero if none of 1 and -1 exist, and that is what the second line is doing here. After setting up the threshold in the `y` column, filling it forward would be straight forward with `na.locf`:

```
df$y <- with(df, ifelse(x == 1, 1, ifelse(x == -1, 0, NA)))
df$y[1] <- if(df$x[1] != 1) 0 else df$y[1]
df$y <- zoo::na.locf(df$y)

df
#     x y
# 1   0 0
# 2   0 0
# 3   1 1
# 4   0 1
# 5   0 1
# 6   1 1
# 7   0 1
# 8   0 1
# 9  -1 0
# 10  0 0
```